# MySQL inconsistent index usage for similar tables: 'Using index' and 'Using where; Using index'

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I'm having trouble optimizing a JOIN to use a composite index. My query is:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.category_id, p1.tag_id, i.rating
    FROM products p1
      INNER JOIN (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE category_id = 662) AS t
        ON t.tag_id = p1.tag_id
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT tax_id, rating FROM ratings WHERE category_id = 662) AS i
        ON i.tax_id = p1.category_id
    LIMIT 5
```

When using EXPLAIN, the INNER JOIN only uses the index, without touching the DB, but the LEFT JOIN returns 'Using where; Using index':

```
1   SIMPLE  tags    ref PRIMARY,category_id         PRIMARY        4    const                           87  100  Using index
1   SIMPLE  p1      ref category_id,category_id_2   topic_id       5    func                            40  100  Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  ratings ref category_id_2,category_id   category_id    8    const,data.p1.category_id        1  100  Using where; Using index
```

I have covering indexes on all three tables and both joins contain a WHERE clause.

Indexes:

```
tags(category_id, tag_id)
ratings(category_id, tax_id, rating)
```

Why does the first join use only the index and not the WHERE and how can I make the second join do the same? Tried all kinds of index combinations as well as forcing index usage, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You know that *Using where* only means that the table is being filtered, nothing more?! That is totally fine.

Comment: @juergend is the table being filtered or the index? I'm trying to only hit the index and not the table. And still, I don't understand why the explain for the first join doesn't output 'using where'.

Answer (score 0):

looking to your code, for better performance ,  you could avoid the subquery   using proper join

```
  SELECT p1.id, p1.category_id, p1.tag_id, i.rating
  FROM products p1
  INNER JOIN tags t  ON t.tag_id = p1.tag_id AND t.category_id = 662
  LEFT JOIN ratings i ON i.tax_id = p1.category_id AND i.category_id = 662
  LIMIT 5
```

In this you you don't force the db engine for buil temporary strcut for manage the result not necessary

*and as  suggested by juergend  in comment to the question the where  word in explain plan  mean only that the table is scan  for filter*